# Always executing if statment have been messing with it but cant figure out why it always executes

Tags: python, python-3.x

i just started programing and i cant figure out why this this if statment alwayse executes

```
Month = input("Enter name of month: ")

if Month == 'September' or 'April' or 'June' or 'November':
    print("There are 30 days in that month")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `in` list

```
Month = input("Enter name of month: ")

if Month in {'September','April','June','November'}:
    print("There are 30 days in that month")
```

Comment: This would throw a type error for comparing a string to a list wouldnt it?

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` should be:

```
if Month == 'September' or Month == 'April' or Month == 'June' or Month == 'November':
```

When you just right a string (in your case 'April' for instance) or a number that is different than 0 it evaluates to something that is not 0 and so the entire condition is evaluated as True and thats why it always executes the if

Comment: So how would i fix that?

Comment: Please re-read my answer

Comment: copy paste his code, that's ctrl+c after you've marked the text here, now select the if in your file and ctrl+v

Comment: will this work if Month in('September' or 'April' or 'June' or 'November'):

Comment: wow im dumb i didnt notice the diffrence at first sorry